# Showing Datas By Parsing Json

Tags: android, json, http-post

I tried to make HTTP Post to a web service and I got a message. Now, I'm trying to parse it using JSON. All I want to do is showing the message in listview after parsing it. However I'm constantly getting a null pointer exception in this line : "      list.setAdapter(numberAdapter); " . I couln't find why it occurs. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> numberAdapter;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        numberAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        list.setAdapter(numberAdapter);

        ....

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `setContetnView`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //missing  
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Make sure you have a `ListView` with id `listView` in the xml layout